# Recover corrupted file in notepad++

Tags: text, notepad++, text-files

I had a text file to save all my important credentials, links and notes. Today when i was working on it, all of a sudden notepad++ crashed. when i reopened np++ the file was empty with zero bytes. I am so stuck now as it has all my credentials.

Is there a way to recover this?

Many thanks

Comment: system restore?

Comment: The same thing happened to me a weeks ago on my Windows 7 laptop xD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you need to recover the file from your latest backup, but I'm guessing that because your asking this question, you don't have one?

If that's the case, then your pretty limited in what you can do. If you have saving of previous versions turned on in Windows you may be able to load an older version by right clicking on the file, go to properties and look at previous versions.

However, more than likely you are going to have to accept that it is gone, learn your lesson and start doing regular backups.

Comment: I did not know about the "restore from previous version" option before. It worked and I got the file. thank you so much